# Missing log records of postfix

Tags: postfix, logging, syslog, rsyslog

Postfix server A relays all emails to postfix server B.
In log file of A, I can see that B accepted email and ID assigned by B, but some IDs are missing in log file of B. I found out that log file of B does not contain any record of certain amounts of time. It logs correctly and time to time it has e.g. 3 or 5 minutes outage without any line. Is that problem of postfix or rsyslogd?

centos 7.3.1611, postfix 2.10.1, 
rsyslogd 7.4.7